# Scheme case error

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to create a word count program in Scheme. I think I've worked out an algorithm that'll count my lines, words, and chars, but when I start to run the program, it tells me "The object #\1 is not applicable." "1" is the first character in the file I'm reading, and it should fall under "else". Everything I look at matches my case statement, so I think I'm doing it right, but clearly something's messed up somewhere. Thank you for your help!

```
(define files
  (lambda (reading n)
    (begin
      (define in (open-input-file reading))
      (let loop ((lines 0)
         (words 0)
         (chars 0)
         (port (read-char in)))
       (case (port)
         ((#\newline)
           (loop (+ lines 1) words (+ chars 1) (read-char in)))
         ((#\space #\tab)
           (loop lines (+ words 1) (+ chars 1) (read-char in)))
         (else (loop lines words (+ chars 1) (read-char in)))))
  (close-input-port in)

  (display lines)
  (display " ")
  (display words)
  (display " ")
  (display chars)
  (newline)
  (display "Top ")
  (display n)
  (display " word(s):")
  (newline)
  '())))
```

Comment: Note that a [fellow user was upset by your deleted question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129578/question-deleted-while-writing-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is fortunately easy to fix.  You've written:

```
(case (port) ...)
```

but that does a `case` on the result of calling the function `port`.  Of course, `port` isn't a function, it's a character, so you just want:

```
(case port ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed one problem, but now I have another... I can probably hunt this new one down with displays and such.

Answer (score 0):

How does the "let loop" know when you've reached the end of the file?  What does read-char return when it hits the end?  Hint: read about the eof-object? predicate.  A predicate is a function that returns #t or #f.  You may need to use a cond rather than a case to use this predicate

Also, the lines, chars and words variables are local to the named let, so you can't print then out "outside".  (Hint: print them inside the loop when (eof-object? port) returns #t.

Style quibble: don't use the name "port" for the char that read-char returns.  "in" is the port (file handle), Maybe you can use "ch" instead of "port".